# How to archive a directory in master and copy to minions using salt

Tags: salt-stack

I know I can use cp.get_dir to download a directory from master to minions, but when the directory contains a lot of files, it's very slow. If I can tar up the directory and then download to minion, it will be much faster.  But I can't find out how to archive a directory at master prior to downloading it to minions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What we do is tar the files manually, then extract them on the minion, as you said. We then either replace or modify any files that should be different from what is in the tar-file. This is a good approach for a configuration file that resides in the .tar file, for example.

To archive the file, we just ssh on the salt master and then use something like `tar -cvzf files.tar.gz <yourfiles>`.

You could also consider having the files on the machines from the start, with a rsync afterwards (via [salt.states.rsync](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.rsync.html) for example). This would just push over the changes in the files, not all the files.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Kai suggested, you could have a minion running on the salt master box and have it tar up the file before you send it down to all the minions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [archive.extracted](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.archive.html) state. The `source` argument uses the same syntax as its counterpart in the [file.managed](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed) state. Example:

```
/path/on/the/minion:
  archive.extracted:
    - source: salt://path/on/the/master/archive.tar.gz
```